# nginx server responding with 404 when testing via /etc/hosts file

Tags: wordpress, nginx, hosting, web-hosting, self-hosting

I've moved over a load of WordPress sites onto our new server which runs on nginx instead of apache, whilst testing them to go live I'm editing my hosts file so that I can view them on the live server before setting them live. All but one have returned a blank page with 404 nginx error, I've triple checked all of the config info but no luck.

They're currently running on no SSL certificates but the one that does seem to work has an SSL on the staging version of the site so I'm trying to figure out if this is what is causing the issue? I'm struggling to get SSL certificates validated on site that aren't live yet, so might be a case of testing one going live and see if that resolves the issue.

```
# Ploi Webserver Configuration, do not remove!
include /etc/nginx/ploi/thelitton.co.uk/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/thelitton-2uuer/thelitton.co.uk/public_html;
    server_name thelitton.co.uk;

    include /etc/nginx/ssl/thelitton.co.uk;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    index index.php index.html;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    # Ploi Configuration, do not remove!
    include /etc/nginx/ploi/thelitton.co.uk/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/thelitton.co.uk-error.log error;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-thelitton-2uuer.sock;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # assets, media
    location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
        expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }

    # svg, fonts
    location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# Ploi Webserver Configuration, do not remove!
include /etc/nginx/ploi/thelitton.co.uk/after/*;
```

Comment: What's you question? Do you have any configuration to share? Just reading that I got no idea what I could do to help.

Comment: Can you tell us which uris you try to access and show us the nginx configuration files? What do you mean by "a load of wordpress sites" - you have multiple wordpress instances? Are you using docker?

Comment: By a load of wordpress sites, it's multiple instances of WordPress. I've added an example nginx config file into the above questions. haven't used docker on any of them just copied and pasted the files and databases from the old server into the new one

Comment: So the one above is that one thats working? At least its looking good and should serve just fine accessed with http/on port 80.

Comment: No this is from an example of one that doesn't work for some reason, they all have the same config file albeit the different root project. I'm wondering if the system I used doesn't allow for non-https sites when testing, as the one that does work has a staging site that has somehow got an SSL certificate on it. @Geilmaker